# Tab space not working

Tags: php

I'm having a problem that I can't add tab space in my image I put some "\t" in my image but it doesn't move where I want it:

```
echo  "\t". "<img src='images/123' alt='Sta' width='47' height='47' />"  ;
```

and also this code doesn't do the same thing:

```
echo  "\t"."STA CECILIA" ;
```

Can you help me how to rearrange this code and how to merge this code so that the output will be a tab space image and another tab space text?

Comment: Have you looked into the source code of your html output? Use CSS if you want to add space between your elements.

Comment: This appear to have nothing to do with MySQL, so I'm removing the tag.

Comment: Im so new about html and php where could i find that source code? sorry for asking. :(

Comment: In your browser do a right-click and then view source (code). You will probably see the tab there but that has no influence on the presentation of your page in the browser.

Comment: i dont know because i operate this code in article (joomla) i use some plug in to run php commands directly in article but i also see that there's no tab space code in my source code sorry for thiss i know that im dumb but help me :/

Comment: @RoyLesterSantos you'd better post an image to explain what you need, everybody is trying to help you but everybody is confusing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To use the php tab, You should use

```
echo "\t";
```

So your output should be

```
echo  "\t"."<img src='images/123' alt='Sta' width='47' height='47' />";
```

If you need to add more space, then you shall handle it by `style`

```
echo  "\t"."<img src='images/123' alt='Sta' width='47' height='47' style='margin:10px />";
```

Comment: that style works but my "Sta cecilia" text down

`echo  "\t". "<img src='images/Sta.png' alt='Sta' width='47' height='47' style='margin:5px' />"  ;
echo  "STA CECILIA" ;`

how to merge this?? i want my output to be the an image with some tab space then the text now :(

Answer (score 0):

**try**

```
    echo 
    "<p style='padding-left: 50px; margin-left: 10px;'>
        <img src='images/123' alt='Sta' width='47' height='47' style='float:left' />
        <span style='display: block'>STA CECILIA</span>
    </p>"
```

**or**

```
    echo 
    "<p style='margin-left: 10px;'>
        <img src='images/123' alt='Sta' width='47' height='47' />
        <span>STA CECILIA</span>
    </p>"
```

Comment: Oh thank god its working but how to add tab space again in the text "sta Cecilia" ?? thankss againn !!

Comment: in the first example try to increase `padding-left` for text tab and `margin-left` for image tab

Comment: ok last thing sorry for thiss mr alquist what is the code for add new line ? I want to have like this " Sta cecilia \ new line College" thankss youre helping me alot

Comment: try this `<span>STA CECILIA<br>College</span>`

Comment: yea it works but the problem is its not align like the first one text "Sta Cecilia but yes the college are in the new line but too far from the first one text because it has padding. the output is sta.cecilia has a tab space while the college does not have